# If IE Statements not working

Tags: html, css, margins

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <html class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <html class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html class="ie ie9 lte9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <html> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html>             <!--<![endif]-->
```

The above code, does not seem to work in the least bit.
The only IE version that my website([The Randy](http://therandy.tk/)) seems to work in is IE9. I thought it was working because of the conditional statements I've input above, but it works in IE9 without those statements as well. If I look at it in IE8 and IE7 I get a broken looking website. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any CSS selector beginning by `.ie9`? I couldn't find any. These conditional classes are the first step for IE "compatibility" (fallback instructions and plain debugging), they won't do anything by themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional comments are not supported in IE 10 and are a bad idea anyway, especially since standards have been set.

You should ALWAYS use feature detection instead of browser detection.

---

EDIT: Reading the Console helps too:

> HTML1513: Extra "`<html>`" tag found. Only one "`<html>`" tag should exist per document.
>   therandy.tk, line 9 character 20
>
> HTML1503: Unexpected start tag.
>   therandy.tk, line 12 character 1
>
> HTML1512: Unmatched end tag.
>   therandy.tk, line 245 character 208
>
> HTML1514: Extra "`<body>`" tag found. Only one "`<body>`" tag should exist per document.
>   therandy.tk, line 247 character 1
>
> HTML1519: Invalid nesting. An "`<a>`" tag should not be placed within another "`<a>`".
>   therandy.tk, line 364 character 97

Comment: I don't see how relying on a JS script could be better than conditional comments/classes for plain CSS workarounds like `display:inline-block` or `table-cell` for IE7-?

Comment: I'm very confused here! When I make changes to the right cell picture (eva longoria pic) it works and displays those changes. But when I make changes again it does not work.

Comment: @FelipeAls Do we really still have to support a browser that's over 6 years old?

Comment: @Kolink I just don't understand!  I have been trying browser specific rules, but it does not work. I'm looking at Content .FTD right...  Whenever I try margin-top:-290px\9;/* IE 8 and below */ the Eva Longoria picture is moved over, but not enough!  So when I try to change that to -200 it moves way over to the middle and does not change, regardless of anything I do, until I change the margin back to -290px.

Comment: Okay I got this to work, by using position absolute and removing the negatives. I'm having some issues with the whole look of the site in IE7, but I think I can fix that too. thankx guys.

Comment: Okay wait. If anyone is still there.                                            Can you take a look at my website in IE7?                                      It looks super off. I don't know where to begin to fix it. Also why such a difference between IE7 and IE8+?

Comment: @Kolink When your client is developing its market in China (many millions of Euro), yes you do support IE7 and do your best in IE6 (we bill more for that, of course). But this is OT, let's take another example of `max-width` with IE8 or gradient with IE9 or whatever: if 1 line of CSS solves a known bug in IE version 6, 7, 8 or 9, why wouldn't someone use conditional classes? They work perfectly fine in all known conditions (and are more performant than conditional stylesheets)

Comment: IE 10 actually recognizes the “pseudocomments” but regards itself as not being IE: the “pseudocomment” with `if !IE` takes effect.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela IE10 does not recognise that comment. `if !IE` is a different kind of conditonial, that hides the content if it fails the test (rather than revealing it if it does). Otherwise, browsers that aren't IE would just see a comment.

Answer (score 2):

In your markup, you have a `<script>` tag before your `<html>` tag opens. That's not valid code, and IE probably doesn't like this. Move that `<script>` so that it's in your document `<head>` instead.

Comment: I think the beginning script tag is generated by Tumblr.

Comment: Pedantically, it;s not actually the `<script>` markup that's the problem, but the "f" character that immediately follows it. Removing just that one character will make the conditional comments take effect. However, the whole block, including the duplicated doctype needs cleaning up and moving to a better location.

Comment: Yes thank you very much. I'm still trying to get some understanding.    How do I remove the "F" character?