# HTML1514: Extra "<body>" tag found

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm using the `IE 11 (version 11.0.9431.0)`, to test our current website and see how it would work when IE 11 will be released with Windows 8.1 mid-October.
What I see on almost all pages is the following message:

`HTML1514: Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document.`

When I look through the source code, there is no second `<body>` anywhere. Is this a IE 11 bug? Is this something I should take seriously? The pages work fine btw...

Thanks.

EDIT:

I don't have access to that website anymore, therefore I can't try any new solutions you guys are posting.

Comment: Can you show some code or the site in question?

Answer (score 10):

If you placed some element (that should appear only inside body) before the `<body>` tag, the `<body>` is inserted [automatically](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tree-construction.html#the-after-head-insertion-mode) by the parser (the "Anything else" paragraph) - and this is still valid HTML because `body` has optional both opening and closing tags. That would mean that the actual `<body>` is the second one the parser sees. Couldn't this be your case?

Comment: Nope, the parser actually puts them in the `body` tag. See here http://jsfiddle.net/r3Fnv/1/

Comment: I guess I could be correct. The parser sees another `<body>` before your tag - not the one in the comment, but the one it automatically inserted.

Comment: There isn't an automatically inserted one, only the one I specified in the code. There's only one body tag in the Results iframe on the jsfiddle, hence it doesn't actually insert another one.

Comment: Don't forget that the IE debug window doesn't update live changes, so if the parser is running through and inserting a new body tag you wouldn't see it (unless IE 11 is different?)

Comment: I can confirm that this solved the problem for me - I had a `<noscript>` tag between the `<head>` and `<body>` when in fact it should have been in one or the other. Putting it in the `<body>` got rid of the complaint.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is you probably have if IE statements, something like:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>     <body class="ie ie9 lte9"> <![endif]-->
```

They don't actually work in IE10, let alone IE11 so that's why you'd be getting the extra tag found.

Comment: They don't work in IE11 => this is a comment. This shouldn't be considered an extra `<body>` tag.

Comment: @duri Yes they are, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947733/if-ie-statements-not-working

Comment: I'm not using these tags. I've searched through the entire source base and the only place where this shows up is in the knockout 2.2.0 debug js files. Could this be a problem?

Comment: @AdrianArsene I would say so yes, is there anyway you can temporarily remove the reference to knockout and test to see if you still get the error?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try, although there's no way I'll give up knockout :)

Comment: @AdrianArsene Haha nah I wasn't suggesting that. If that is the problem, maybe you can raise a ticket with their team.

Answer (score 2):

The problem (which is present in IE 10, too) is caused by the element

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_clients/binck_nl/data/js/analytics.js?nl_1377516473" ></script>
```

It probably modifies the DOM so that IE gets confused.

Comment: We had the same problem.  Solved by moving the script to the body rather than the header.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably your body tag in the css.  Replace the body-tag in the css with a class for example .bodystyle {} and refere in your html to it with the  tag.  That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this may be a very late for suggesting. But, just to help others the probable cause may be any iframe coming in the page which has body tag

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to that website anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same effect showing up in IE10 and IE11 saying there was an extra body tag in the console.  What fixed it for me was that I found an element outside of the body that was a div for a spinner while the page loads that should have been within the body.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it may be content in the header part which Edge wants in the body part. (If you have a header part).

This works in any other browser but Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing: `<header><title>something</title></header>` from the  tag body.  Now edge no longer complains.